# Символическая ссылка linux, права доступа

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Создать символическую ссылку на /root. Можно ли ее использовать?

```
ln -s /root link_root
bash: cd: link_root: Отказано в доступе
```

Вопрос такой: можно ли ее использовать с другими правами? Правильно ли я понимаю, что только root может перейти по ней?

Comment: Правильно понимаете. `avp@avp-desktop:~$ ll -d /root
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Mar 23 21:30 /root/
avp@avp-desktop:~$`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант

```
nano /etc/sudoers
```

Дать юзеру команды ln (test)

```
test      ALL=(ALL:ALL) /bin/ln
```

> Проверить

```
test@ubuntu:/home/aa$ sudo -ll
[sudo] password for test: 

User test may run the following commands on ubuntu:


Sudoers entry:
  RunAsUsers: ALL
  RunAsGroups: ALL
  Commands:
     /bin/ln
```

/

```
sudo ln -s /root link_root
```

**Нужно обратить внимания на пара доступа на каталог ROOT**

Но символьную ссылку сделать получится

Права на каталог ROOT

```
drwx------   6 root root  4096 апр 20 21:09 root
```

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что только root может перейти по ней?

**ДА**!